# A proof on groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, finite-groups

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n>1$, let $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times := \{1, \dots, n-1\}$.

For positive integers $a$ and $n$, show that $ax \bmod{n} = 1$ has a solution if and only if $\gcd(a,n)=1$.

Then using my proof for the first part i am to prove that $(\mathbb{Z}_n^\times,\cdot)$, where $a\cdot b := (ab) \bmod{n}$, is a group if $n$ is a prime.

I have no idea AT all how to do this proof. The only thing that i have done so far was to state that i needed to prove the first part both directions as it is an iff statement.

Also the only thing that i know is that $a\cdot b + qn = ab$, that $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is addition mod n

I was hoping someone would show me how to do this proof.

Also i didnt know what a good title would be, so if you have a better idea feel fee to change it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** let $a \in G$. Then $ax=1$ has a solution if and only if $g$ generates the group (as in , $\langle a \rangle=G$.)

What are the generators for $\mathbb Z_n^{\times}$? For example, can $3$ generate $\mathbb Z_6^{\times}$? Notice that its order is $2$, what is special about this?

Recall that the order of  a subgroup $H \subset G$ divides the order of $G$.

What is $|\langle a \rangle|$?

Answer (score 0):

If $\gcd(a,n) = 1$ then there exist integers $r,s$ such that $ra + sn = 1$. What happens when you reduce this equation mod $n$?